# LinearLayoutManager for recycler view and Scroll Listener..?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I had `recyclerview` in my `fragment` tab, 1 declare variables

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (Context)
```

in the `OnCreate` method, and in my `Recyclerview` i make

```
scrollListener var = new scroll (mLayoutManager);
```

which both require mLinearlayoutmanagers are the same and in case of error..
this case

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Context);     
var scrollListener = new scroll(mLayoutManager);
// This successful working properly
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager); 
// This successful but if in the tab on the move will occur error but I found the solution
mRecyclerView.AddOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

successful but .. :

```
//mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Context);       
var scrollListener = new scroll(mLayoutManager); // not working properly
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Context)); 
// this successful  if in the tab on the move will not be an error.
mRecyclerView.AddOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

any one can help me..??

Comment: A little confused about your real question?

Comment: You've already asked this question in a different form. I left an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354809/how-to-get-linearlayoutmanager-from-recyclerview